# Get specific key and value from multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, object, webdriver-io

**Status:**

```
// WebdriverIO log function

browser.log('browser').then(function(logs) {
    console.log(logs.value);
});
```

returns me the following Array:

```
[ { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 42:14 "foo"',
    timestamp: 1485857149752 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 43:14 "bar"',
    timestamp: 1485857149752 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 46:14 Array[6]',
    timestamp: 1485857149755 },
  { level: 'SEVERE',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',
    timestamp: 1485857149834 } ]
```

**Goal:**

I want to to create a single method that I can use later that returns me a list of the log entries. That would be in this case with my example application:

```
foo
bar
```

I do not know how to loop for only the "message" key with its value.

To filter so to get only "foo" or "bar" I would use RegEx or .split function.

Comment: you want to filter to get a list of only the `message`s for instance?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - value from the last message?

Comment: How would it know to remove the quotes from `"foo"` and `"bar"` and change `Array[6]` to `[Array]`?

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah I would need that to use that as a helper function for further tests. So the scenario is that I test a app with mocha/webdriverio and want to check the console logs if a peer connection has been established etc.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, that is also a console message from the demo app. The real scenario would not have those errors but only console logs for connections established and so on (webRTC conferencing tests).

Comment: @JLRishe Removed the [Array] part from my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using [**`Array.prototype.reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arr = [{
  level: 'INFO',
  message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 42:14 "foo"',
  timestamp: 1485857149752
}, {
  level: 'INFO',
  message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 43:14 "bar"',
  timestamp: 1485857149752
}, {
  level: 'INFO',
  message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 46:14 Array[6]',
  timestamp: 1485857149755
}, {
  level: 'SEVERE',
  message: 'https://localhost:3000/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',
  timestamp: 1485857149834
}];

let res = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (b.level === 'INFO') {
    a.push(b.message.split(" ").pop().replace(/"/g, ""));
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Remember to implement a check before chaining all of

```
b.message.split(" ").pop().replace(/"/g, "")
```

to avoid getting null pointer exceptions.

Sidenote:

Wasn't specified by the OP, but in case the message you want to collect contains spaces too, you can replace the split above and use [@JLRishe's regex instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41955150/3993662)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if any of the messages contains a space.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks for the heads up, I added a version that covers that case. btw. yours doesn't work either for the same case.

Comment: Nice regex @JLRishe

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
var log = [ { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 42:14 "foo"',
    timestamp: 1485857149752 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 43:14 "bar"',
    timestamp: 1485857149752 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 46:14 Array[6]',
    timestamp: 1485857149755 },
  { level: 'SEVERE',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',
    timestamp: 1485857149834 } ]

var messages = log
    .filter(function (entry) { return entry.level === 'INFO'; })
    .map(function (entry) { 
        return entry.message.replace(/^([^\s]+\s){2}"?|"$/g, ''); 
    });

console.log(messages)
```

This doesn't convert `"foo"` to `foo` and so on, but it's not clear how you're expecting the code to do that (I've added a comment about that to your question).